# NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH and CustomerCookie in Nop 3.0

Tags: cookies, autofac, nopcommerce

how the system can do it like this? for the register user, even the CustomerCookie value can't be stored after restart the browser even stated expired age is 1 year in the code. But for the guest it's working, both of those used same code to set CustomerCookie.

I know there are two place to handle the user cookies.
1. CustomerCookie located in WebWorkContext. this cookie will be stored 1 year.

```
 cookieExpires = 24*365; //TODO make configurable
 cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(cookieExpires);
```

2. for registered user, it will use FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName to save cookie and will update CustomerCookie value once user login successful.

I did bellow testing:
1. For guest
  open the page without login and close all the browser then open the browser again. two time's Nop.customer's value are the same, which means guest cookie saved successful.

2. For registered user
   step 1. open the page and login with user, I found the cookie value NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH is stored but it's session time expire age. cookie Nop.customer's value is set to  registered user guid, the expire age is 1 year indeed.
   step 2. Then I close all the browser and opened again, I fund the CustomerCookie's value changed to a guest value, the saved cookie value at step 1 is gone which should be expired 1 years latter.